# Pinch and zoom not working on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I am unable to do pinch and zoom on ipad, I guess that the below given code may be effecting the code,
Please give any perfect solution.
Is there any issue with the binding of body child events or need to calculate the touches in different variables, and do manual calculation.

```
     ///I-Pad evenet Binding
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $("body").children().bind('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', function () {
           var touches = event.changedTouches, first = touches[0], type = "";
           switch (event.type) {
               case "touchstart": type = "mousedown";
                   break;
               case "touchmove": type = "mousemove";
                   break;
               case "touchend": type = "mouseup";
                   break;
               default: return;
           }

           var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
           simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                  first.screenX, first.screenY,
                  first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                  false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);
           if (touches.length < 2) {
               first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
               event.preventDefault();
           }

       });


   (function () {
            var last_x = null, last_y = null, w_area = workarea[0],
                panning = false, keypan = false, dopanning = false;

            $("#svgroot").bind('mousemove mouseup', function (evt) {
                if (dopanning === false) return;
                var clientxnew = +$("#svgcontent")[0].getAttribute("x"),
                clientynew = +$("#svgcontent")[0].getAttribute("y");
                clientxnew += (evt.clientX - last_x);
                clientynew += (evt.clientY - last_y);
                last_x = evt.clientX;
                last_y = evt.clientY;
                //this.setAttribute("viewBox", vb.join(' '));
                // updateCanvas(true);
                $("#svgcontent").show();
                $("#svgcontent")[0].setAttribute("x", clientxnew);
                $("#svgcontent")[0].setAttribute("y", clientynew);
                svgedit.select.getSelectorManager().selectorParentGroup.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + clientxnew + "," + clientynew + ")");
                if (evt.type === 'mouseup') { dopanning = false; }

                return false;
            }).mousedown(function (evt) {

                var mouse_target = svgCanvas.getMouseTarget(evt);
                if (svgCanvas.getMode() == "text" || svgCanvas.getMode() == "textedit") {
                    dopanning = false; return;
                }
                if ((mouse_target.id.indexOf("grouplayerdragged") > -1 || mouse_target.id.indexOf("hotspot") > -1 ||
                mouse_target.id.indexOf("clonediv") > -1 || mouse_target.tagName === "text")) { dopanning = false; return; }
                if (selectedElement != null) {
                    dopanning = false; return;
                }
                if (evt.button === 0) {
                    dopanning = true;
                    last_x = evt.clientX;
                    last_y = evt.clientY;
                    svgCanvas.clearSelection(true);
                    return false;

                }
            });

            $(window).mouseup(function () {
                panning = false;
                dopanning = false;
            });
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. It seems that binding any touch event to an element causes the _pinch to zoom_  to stop working

Answer (score 0):

you should use gesturechange. try this way (this is not your exact solution but you can hack it)

```
var angle = 0;
var newAngle;
var scale = 1;
var newScale;

function saveChanges() {
    angle = newAngle;
    scale = newScale;
}
function getAngleAndScale(e) {

    // Don't zoom or rotate the whole screen
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rotation and scale are event properties
    newAngle = angle + e.rotation;
    newScale = scale * e.scale;
    // Combine scale and rotation into a single transform
    var tString = "scale(" + newScale + ")";
    document.getElementById("theDiv").style.webkitTransform = tString;
}
function init() {
    // Set scale and rotation during gestures
    document.getElementById("theDiv").addEventListener("gesturechange", getAngleAndScale, false);
    // Preserve scale and rotation when gesture ends
    document.getElementById("theDiv").addEventListener("gestureend", saveChanges, false);
}
```

---

<**body**>

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:scrool;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
   <img id="theDiv" style="width:100%;" src="http://animal.discovery.com/guides/wild-birds/gallery/mallard_duck.jpg" />
</div>
```

[Try this on your ipad](http://ugurozpinar.com/code/drag/)